# Javascript. How to detect when the window.document has changed?

Tags: javascript, window, document

The window.document gets changed quiet often, for example, when you move from one url to another or when you call document.reload(true);

The document itself has a readyState which is perfect and a readystatechange event to track any changes. However if you put an addEventListener to the document for the readyState event and the document gets renewed, the addEventListener will not exist anymore and the method will never be called.

So I like to attach one everytime the document gets renewed in the window object. So is there a way to detect that?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to either have your own javascript present in every web page so that script could reinstall the event handler as each page is loaded or you would have to do this from a browser plug-in that can monitor every single page as it's loaded.

Somewhat by definition, all scripts from a page are cleared when a new page is loaded so it is not possible to have a script from one page survive into the next page.

One other idea: If all the pages of interest were on the same domain and on your domain, it might be possible to have a parent frame that regularly monitors the child frame and keeps resetting an event handler on it everytime the document changes.  But, because of the same-origin-policy safety restrictions, this could only work if all frames were on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting current browsers and don't care about legacy support, check out the History API, as it allows you to appear to the user to be going to new pages (the URL in the address bar changes and back/fwd appear to work as they are supposed) without refreshing your JavaScript context.

See a demo here: http://html5demos.com/history

And read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: I am targeting mainly the iOS Safari 5.1 browser so I don't mind about the legacy indeed. However the history won't fix the issue I am having, detecting if the window.document get's renewed.

Comment: the history api would let you _override_ document "renewal". Otherwise, I guess you could listen for the `"beforeunload"` event, but it won't really matter 'cause your scripts and all JS Objects are gonna get wiped right after it happens anyway...

Comment: Indeed JKing now you are talking. The 'unload' event does get fired when the document is being wiped indeed, but i actually want the 'rightafterunload' ;-) event